# Why could be the reason a Journey decreases its total populations along the path?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Thank you for your time! I have an issue here with the decrease ammount of total population along the path... I dont understand why it is happening, the reasons of this decrease... 
Here you have a Iamge of the situation: 
[image]

Comment: Do you have any Domain Exlcusion or Supression List set in Email Activity?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to write your question. We haven´t any exclusion list and we only use the suppression list when making single sends. By the way, is it possible to use a suppression list in Journey Builder?

Answer (score 0):

- The first decrease (1395 > 1392) is probably related to email bounce
- The rest happens on waiting periods - which can be either unsubscribes or people hitting an exit criteria (or goal with exit)

Check your unsubscribe rates and exit criteria for this journey.

Comment: I´ve checked the unsubscribe rates and are very low, not enough to fulffill the difference from 1226 to 900....

Comment: About the exit criteria... There should be an issue regarding the formula... Could be the reason but im not sure about it